# Distinct Dates Group BY Year

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct, using

How to find the distinct dates in a year using Oracle?

```
id    sent_date
1     2017-05-01 
1     2017-05-01 
1     2017-06-01
1     2016-06-01
```

Ignore the duplicate sent_date  for a Id in the same year.

**Output**

```
count(*)   id   year
2           1   2017
1           1   2016
```

**EDIT:**

Thisis my query

```
select distinct(count(sent_date)), id , extract (year from sent_date)
from test
GROUP BY id, extract (year from sent_date).
```

3 1 2017 (wrong)-- expecting the count as 2 1 1 2016 –

Comment: SO is not for questions like "How to do this", so please do some search, try some code and then, if you have an issue with your code, feel free to post a question here.

Comment: Thisis my query
select distinct(count(sent_date)),   id , extract (year from sent_date) from test GROUP BY id, extract (year from sent_date).     
3           1   2017 (wrong)-- expecting the count as 2 
1           1   2016

Comment: Please do not add comments to clarify the question, but edit it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` is wrongly positioned in your query; you simply need:

```
select count(distinct sent_date), id , extract (year from sent_date)
from test
group by id, extract (year from sent_date)
```

Also, `DISTINCT` is not a function, so the syntax `DISTINCT(...)` does not make sense.